# How to change text field cursor position in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I have list of text suggestions chip view above textfield, when user clicking chip I am appending the text into textfield. after that I want to move the cursor to the end position. I couldn't find solution for this in Jetpack compose. earlier we used `editText.setSelection(position)` to change cursor position in android views.

How to set a cursor position in jetpack compose Textfield?

```
         OutlinedTextField(
                    value = value,
                    onValueChange = { value = it },
                    maxLines = 8,
                    label = {
                        Text(
                            text = "Content",
                            maxLines = 1
                        )
                    },

                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(200.dp),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(2.dp),

                    )
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

We can use `TextFieldValue` to change cursor position

Initialise the `TextFieldValue` just like this

```
 var textFieldValueState by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            TextFieldValue(
                text = ""
            )
        )
    }
```

after initialising it set the `TextFieldValue` just like the below

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = textFieldValueState,
    onValueChange = { textFieldValueState = it },
    ...
    )
```

To append additional text and for cursor selection, follow these steps

```
IconButton(modifier = Modifier.then(Modifier.size(48.dp)),
     onClick = {
        val value = textFieldValueState.text.plus("****")
        textFieldValueState = TextFieldValue(
        text = value,
        selection = TextRange(value.length-2)
        )
     })
```

[image: reference image]

`TextFieldValue` `text` and `selection` variables are not changeable so we need to create new `TextFieldValue` to set the text and cursor position.

Comment: Don't work on FireTV.

Answer (score 3):

An example of how to insert new text at the current position of the input cursor. And move the cursor to a new position

```
// TextField
var textFieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
TextField(textFieldValue, onValueChange = { textFieldValue = it })

private fun insertText(textFieldValue: TextFieldValue, insertText: String): TextFieldValue {
    val maxChars = textFieldValue.text.length
    val textBeforeSelection = textFieldValue.getTextBeforeSelection(maxChars)
    val textAfterSelection = textFieldValue.getTextAfterSelection(maxChars)
    val newText = "$textBeforeSelection$insertText$textAfterSelection"
    val newCursorPosition = textBeforeSelection.length + insertText.length
    return TextFieldValue(
        text = newText,
        selection = TextRange(newCursorPosition)
    )
}

// use
onClick = { 
 textFieldValue = insertText(textFieldValue, " #$tag")
}
```

Comment: did'n work for me

Answer (score 3):

a "*selection*" should be used and *TextFieldValue*:

```
@Composable
fun CustomTextField() {
    val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(viewState.contextText)) }}
   val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

BasicTextField(
    value = textState.value,
    onValueChange = {
                textState.value = it
                viewModel.onContextText(it.text)
            }
    modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
    textStyle = ...
)

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    focusRequester.requestFocus()
}

 // Set cursor position to the end when the text changes
DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    textState.value = textState.value.copy(
        selection = TextRange(textState.value.text.length)
    )
    onDispose { }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    var textState by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello, world!") }
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        BasicTextField(
            value = TextFieldValue(textState, selection = TextRange(textState.length)),
            onValueChange = { textState = it.text },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .focusRequester(focusRequester),
        )
        Button(
            onClick = {
                // Request focus and set the cursor at the end of the text when the button is clicked
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
            },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp)
        ) {
            Text("Move Cursor to End")
        }
    }
}
```

`val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }`:
This line declares a FocusRequester object using the remember function. The FocusRequester is used to request focus on the **BasicTextField** programmatically.

when the button is clicked, it calls **focusRequester.requestFocus()** to request focus on the **BasicTextField** programmatically.

[image]