# Jetpack compose: cursor in the end of a TextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Using Jetpack Compose `BasicTextField` component, I want to create the following effect:

**Initial text**

[image: Initial text]

**Then input some value**

[image: Text with Value]

After that, move the cursor for index 2 for example and put a value (let's say 3), in the end. I want the following effect:

**Desired effect**

[image: Desired effect]

In other words, I want that the value is inputted in the current index and force the cursor to the end (and can change the cursor again if I want, and redo the process). I can force the cursor to stay always in the end, but I don't know how to do this in Jetpack compose.

**Note:** I have tried solutions using `TextRange`, but this locks my selection

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dos this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70908515/how-to-change-text-field-cursor-position-in-jetpack-compose help?

Comment: @Raghunandan, that solution restricts selection and changing cursor position manually as the OP has mentioned.

Comment: @Abhimanyu oops. then i misread the question.

Comment: @IGGI have you found the answer you are looking for?

Answer (score 6):

The correct answer to put the cursor at the end AND be able to select, copy, etc. the text in the TextField is:

```
var textFieldValueState by remember {
    mutableStateOf(
        TextFieldValue(
            text = textValue,
            selection = TextRange(textValue.length)
        )
    )
}

TextField(
    value = textFieldValueState,
    onValueChange = { textFieldValueState = it }
)
```

Answer (score 5):

To move cursor to a position set the TextRange(position).
For example, if you want to move the cursor to end of text do

```
TextField(
    value = TextFieldValue(
        text = textValue,
        selection = TextRange(textValue.length)
    ),
    onValueChange = {
        textValue = it.text
    }
)
```

Comment: Don't know if this works before, but from my side, it is causing infinite loops when start inputting:


"onValueChange: TextFieldValue(text='f', selection=TextRange(1, 1), composition=TextRange(0, 1))"

Comment: Nice, but this does not help you move the cursor afterwards (as OP requested)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is

```
TextField(
    value = TextFieldValue(
        text = textValue,
        selection = TextRange(textValue.length). // TextRange(0, textValue.length) -> Select that text in a color
    ),
    onValueChange = {
        textValue = it.text
    }
)
```

if it works please make it up

Comment: This solution restricts selection and changing cursor position manually as the OP has mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this. Cursor moves to end after any text change, and it possible to move cursor mannualy.

```
var str by remember {
    mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(""))
}

TextField(
    value = str,
    onValueChange = {
        str = if (str.text != it.text)
            TextFieldValue( text = it.text, selection = TextRange(it.text.length))
        else
            it   
    }
)
```